# Kotlin + Intelij + HtmlUnit: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: kotlin, htmlunit

I'm using HtmlUnit for my project, when I tried the below code:

```
webClient.webConnection = FalsifyingWebConnection(webClient) {
            fun getResponse(request: WebRequest): WebResponse {
                if(request.getUrl().getPath().toLowerCase().equals("some url i don't need ")) {
                    return createWebResponse(request, "", "application/javascript");
                }

            return super.getResponse(request);
        }
    }
```

Error happens at **FalsifyingWebConnection(webClient)**, which says:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a way to instantiate an object with a method override, than you need an object expression:

```
webClient.webConnection = object : FalsifyingWebConnection(webClient) {
    override fun getResponse(request: WebRequest): WebResponse {
        if(request.getUrl().getPath().toLowerCase().equals("some url i don't need ")) {
            return createWebResponse(request, "", "application/javascript");
        }

        return super.getResponse(request);
    }
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html